# OOP: how to add automatic context to exceptions

Tags: php, oop, exception

I have a class that receives some initialization values in its constructor and uses them to implement an interface. My code creates several objects from this class, with different initialization values.

Whenever an exception occurs in one of the methods, the stacktrace shows which class and method threw the exception, but not which *object* did.

Therefore, I would like to wrap every exception that leaves my class with some additional information, including the original initialization values that object received in its constructor. This should happen both to exceptions that I throw myself (that's trivial) and to ones thrown by the runtime (such as NPEs) and by libraries used by my class.

Of course, I could wrap every public method in a try/catch:

```
public function whatever(...)
{
    try {

        // ...

    } catch (\Throwable $e) {
        throw $this->wrapException($e);
    }
}
```

But adding those 4 lines to every public method and indenting the body of every method one level, just to get more readable stacktraces, violates the [DRY principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don't_repeat_yourself) and is plain ugly.

Is there a better way? A generic OOP design pattern or maybe some PHP-specific trick that can address this issue, such as magic method names?

Comment: Wasn't `try`/`catch` construct specifically designed to do what you wish to do? Seems like you just wish to reinvent the wheel with slightly less edges.

Comment: Why don't you add the object itself to the exception when you throw it? I usually create a custom exception class for that including stuff like `__toString()` methods for easy logging...

Comment: @Nordenheim So you suggest copy/pasting those 4 lines into every public method and indenting the body of every public method one level, just to get more comprehensible stacktraces. I think it violates the [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don't_repeat_yourself) principle and is just plain ugly.

Comment: @arkascha That would work for exceptions I create and throw myself, but not for exceptions thrown by the runtime (such as NPE) or by libraries used by my class.

Comment: "DRY" is very questionable... I prefer "explicit over implicit", since it is more transparent and readable.